# Javafx the UI freezes when my application tries to display a large amount of data

Tags: java, javafx, linechart, series

I have a GUI that contains a Line chart and I have 6 series each series has a very big number of samples e.g  the first serie has 9000 points.

I tried to add the serie to my lineChart and then to display it.
When I start my app I can see the 6 plotted series but  the GUI freezes/hangs

That's why i tried to use multi threading :) but i don't really know how I use it in this case

Has Someone an Idea how to prevent this freezing by adding a large amount of data

Here is my code:

```
// listOfSensortDataArrays is a List of 1d arrays it contains 6  1d arrays and each array has the length 9150 

for (int j = 0; j <6; j++) {
// I create an empty serie
XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = newXYChart.Series<Number,Number>();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfSensorDataArrays.get(j).length; i++) {
// I fill the serie with the data from listOfSensorDataArrays
series.add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(i,listOfSensorDataArrays.get(j)[i]));
}        
// and here I add the serie to my LineChart       
lineChart.getData().add(series);}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your used hard- and software. I'm not in javafx but maybe theres more than just your code.

Comment: Aren't 56000 points vertically alligned a little bit to big for a screen?

Comment: no they are 6 series  and each series contains 9000 point they will separately displayed.